# RPS Command with reactions not working - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot in discord.js v13 and I need to make a rock, paper, scissors command and I made the following code: (I left out some parts because I couldn't post it, mainly embeds like NoResponse messages, so if something doesn't have a value, the name probably suggests what it's supposed to be!

Code:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

You lost! :confused:")
    .setColor(colors.COLOR);
const cancelled = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(":x: Cancelled! You failed to respond in time!")
    .setColor(colors.COLOR);
module.exports = {
    name: "rps",
    aliases: [],
    async execute(client, message, args) {

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [noResponse] }).then(msg => {
            msg.react("");
            msg.react("✂️");
            msg.react("");

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', '✂️', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            }

            const choices = ['', '✂️', ''];
            const me = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
            msg.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 20000, error: ['time'] }).then(
                async (collected) => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();
                    const result = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("Results", `${reaction.emoji.name}`)
                        .addField("Your choice:", `${me}`)
                        .setColor(colors.COLOR)
                    msg.edit(result);

                    if ((me === "" && reaction.emoji.name === "✂️") ||
                        (me === "✂️" && reaction.emoji.name === "") ||
                        (me === "" && reaction.emoji.name === "")) {
                        message.channel.send({ embeds: [youLost] });
                    } else if (me === reaction.emoji.name) {
                        return message.channel.send({ embeds: [resultTie] });
                    } else {
                        return message.channel.send({ embeds: [youWin] });
                    }
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    message.channel.send({ embeds: [cancelled] });
                });
        });
    }
}
```

However, when I run the bot it sends the message, and adds the reactions, but then when the time runs out, it gives the canceled embed (it timed out) even though I reacted to the message.

I tried fixing it in multiple ways but I don't know what it is. Is it something that changed in discord.js v13?

I don't know how to fix this. Does somebody know?

Comment: You're sending the cancelled embed from a catch block, suggesting that something is erroring out inside your collection callback.

Comment: Ye but how can i fix this? Cuz when i removed the .catch it still didnt work

Comment: What happens when you remove the catch?

Comment: It just says that i won all the time

Comment: Can you verify your 'reaction` variable isn't null/undefined?

Comment: It is, how can i fix that?

Comment: It's unclear because you have left out a lot of your other code, but you might be overwriting a variable or the collector is empty.